# Is it a good architecture pattern to use API + Traditional web views + front-end frameworks on the same application?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, backend

For those who understand about software architecture, I would like to know if it is a good pattern to create an application that exposes an API to be consumed by a front-end application (React/Vue/Angular) for the end-user (people) and also renders traditional web views to be used in the administration area?

All of this inside the same server and basically the same application meaning in the root folder of the app I would have to folders: front-end (React/Vue/etc) + back-end (Express/Laravel, etc.)

The back-end not only exposes an API for the front-end but also renders web views for the administration area

The front-end consumes the APIs and renders views for the enduser.

I like this approach because I don't have to fill the front-end (React/Vue/Angular) with views for the administration area, but I don't know if it is something that other people or companies do?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, why not?!

Many headless CMS's already do this. They have an API, a UI for the admin and then let you build your frontend on top of that.

But then again, why not also decouple your backend and admin views?

Expose admin actions on the API and then you can write your UI in whatever you want. You can still use Vue/Angular/React, but it would be stored in a separate repository from the public frontend and potentially be served from elsewhere too.

This may give you greater flexibility and scalability long term, but only you can decide which is the right solution for you.